# Parse NSString with SBJSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, sbjson

Quick question:

How do I parse a NSString using SBJSON4
The string is an UTF-8 encoded JSON string from a web REST api. 
I need an NSDIctionary with the parsed data. The string is guaranteed to be a complete JSON document.

```
   @interface NSOperationParseJSON ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<JSONParseDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringToParse;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SBJson4Parser *jsonParser;

@end

@implementation NSOperationParseJSON

- (instancetype)initWithJSONString:(NSString *)jsonString andDelegate:(id<JSONParseDelegate>)delegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _delegate = delegate;
        _stringToParse = jsonString;
        _jsonParser = [[SBJson4Parser alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - OVERRIDEN 

- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (self.isCancelled) {
            return;
        }

        SBJson4ParserStatus responseCode = [self.jsonParser parse:[self.stringToParse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if (responseCode == SBJson4ParserComplete) {

        } else if (SBJson4ParserError) {

        }

    }
}
```

Where do I get the response?

Comment: why don't you use NSJSON ?

Comment: Non-standard json. I have some keys that are like "@data" ... and NSJSON can't handle these kind of json.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read up on the documentation. Version 4’s interface is quite different from previous versions. Although it supports some modes of working that NSJSONSerialisation does not, such as working with uncomplete JSON streams, it doesn't support non-standard JSON (unless there is a bug I missed).

If you still want to explore it, here are two examples:

https://github.com/stig/ChunkedDelivery or https://github.com/stig/DisplayPretty